# Task.Result/wait(..) is indefinitely waits if waited on chain of tasks have 'unwrapped' task, whereas successfully completes if 'async/await' is used

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

**Environment:** Windows Server 2012, .net 4.5, Visual Studio 2013.

Note: not **UI** Application (so not related to famous async/await/synchronizationcontext problem)(reference: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Async-library-methods-should-consider-using-Task-ConfigureAwait-false-)

### Edit

It was a typo which caused deadlock. I have pasted below sample snippet (pseudo) which caused deadlock. Basically, instead of composing whenall based on 'childtasks', I did it on 'outer tasks' :(. Looks like I shouldn't write 'async' code while watching TV :).

And I have left the original code snippets as it is to give the context for Kirill's response as it indeed answers my first question (difference with async/await and unwrap in my previous two code snippets). The deadlock kind of distracted me to see the actual issue :).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task t = IndefinitelyBlockingTask();
    t.Wait();            
}        
static Task IndefinitelyBlockingTask()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    Task task = FooAsync();
    tasks.Add(task);
    Task<Task> continuationTask = task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        Task.Delay(10000);
        List<Task> childtasks = new List<Task>();
        ////get child tasks
        //now INSTEAD OF ADDING CHILD TASKS, i added outer method TASKS. Typo :(:)!
        Task wa = Task.WhenAll(tasks/*TYPO*/);
        return wa;
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    tasks.Add(continuationTask);
    Task unwrappedTask = continuationTask.Unwrap();
    tasks.Add(unwrappedTask);
    Task whenall = Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
    return whenall;
}
```

**Code Snippet which waits indefinitely when 'unwrapped' continuation task has been added to aggregated/chain of tasks** I have pasted below *pseudo (pattern/idiom blocks in my actual app - not on sample)* code snippet (#1), which indefinitely waits when 'unwrapped' task has been added to the list. And VS Debugger 'Debugger + windows + threads' window shows the thread is simply blocking on **ManualResetEventSlim.Wait**.

**Code Snippet which works with async/await, and removal of unwrapped task** Then I removed (randomly while debugging), this unwrap statement and used async/await in the lambda (please see below). Surprisingly it works. But I am not sure why :(?.

**Questions**

1. Aren't using unwrap and async/await serve the same purpose in below code snippets? I simply preferred snippet #1 initially as I just want to avoid too much generated code as the debugger is not so friendly (especially in error scenarios where the exception is propagating via chained tasks - the callstack in exception shows movenext rather than my actual code). If it is, then is it a bug in TPL?
2. What am I missing? which approach is preferred if they are same?

**Note on Debugger + Tasks windows** 'Debugger + Tasks' window does not show any details (note it is not properly (at least my understanding) working in my environment as it never shows unscheduled tasks and oribitarily shows active tasks)

**Code snippet which indefinitely waits on ManualResetEventSlim.Wait**

```
static Task IndefinitelyBlockingTask()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    Task task = FooAsync();
    tasks.Add(task);
    Task<Task> continuationTask = task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        List<Task> childTasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            var ct = FooAsync();
            childTasks.Add(ct);
        }
        Task wa = Task.WhenAll(childTasks.ToArray());
        return wa;
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    tasks.Add(continuationTask);
    Task unwrappedTask = continuationTask.Unwrap();
    //commenting below code and using async/await in lambda works (please see below code snippet)
    tasks.Add(unwrappedTask);
    Task whenall = Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
    return whenall;
}
```

**Code snippet which works with async/await in lambda rather than unwrap**

```
static Task TaskWhichWorks()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    Task task = FooAsync();
    tasks.Add(task);
    Task<Task> continuationTask = task.ContinueWith(async t =>
    {
        List<Task> childTasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            var ct = FooAsync();
            childTasks.Add(ct);
        }
        Task wa = Task.WhenAll(childTasks.ToArray());
        await wa.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    tasks.Add(continuationTask);
    Task whenall = Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
    return whenall;
}
```

**Callstack which shows blocking code**

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim.Wait(int millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.SpinThenBlockingWait(int millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)    Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalWait(int millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)    Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(int millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)    Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait() Unknown
```

Comment: Are you running from a ui application and does fooasync contain an await?

Comment: @Linky: it is not 'UI' application. And also note that the block is not happening because of 'await' - so i think it is not related to well known problem of await with UI/synchronization context (reference: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Async-library-methods-should-consider-using-Task-ConfigureAwait-false-)

Comment: So you're running in a Service/Console application without any special synchronization context?

Comment: @Linky: yes, and also note the the code works when 'await' is used (so its not related to that at all, i guess). It blocks iff i include 'unwrapped continuation task' in the chain of tasks am waiting. If i removed unwrapped task and simply use await everything is fine.

Comment: This is really strange. I have pretty much the same setup as you. Running FooAsync with an dummy implementation of 'await Task.Delay' in Console and 'Wait()'ing or 'await'ing on it works as expected, running the same in UI deadlocks in UI application. Curious to see the answer what else could be the problem.

Comment: @Linky: the deadlock is very easy to repro from GUI as it is well known problem with await (especially the default behavior of saving synchronization context). the video i gave nicely explains all details. And note that sample psudeo code if i use in simple console app works - but it is not working in my production code which contain nested tasks (one more depth and more continuations) - but that is definitely the usage. i am simply invoking wait/result on the 'aggregated task which contain chained/nested tasks). Its strange how come removing unwrapped task and await works.

Comment: @Dreamer, how about you come up with a repro that would actually demonstrate the problem then?

Comment: @Krill: it is very difficult to repro in a simple console app as the aggregated task is formed based not he system it is managing. And the question is pretty straightforward: what is the major  difference between two patterns (semantics) i showed (async/await and unwrapped task), and what may contribute to blocking the thread...(note threads window don't show other threads, tasks window is empty to see if there are multiple threads are waiting on this event)

Comment: @Dreamer, ok I am clearly not smart enough to spot what the difference is right away, but here's an interesting riddle for you and it *might* point you in the right direction (using a unit test project, no `SynchronizationContext`): if you implement your FooAsync() as `return Task.Delay(500)`, and then time the execution of both methods, in my case `TaskWhichWorks` completes in roughly 500ms whereas `IndefinitelyBlockingTask` takes a full second. If the two bits of code were truly equivalent, that would not be the case.

Comment: @Krill: appreciate your efforts :). Yes, both are not exactly same as 'unwrap' is using TaskExtensions and whereas 'await' is generating code and simply straightway returns the task from the state machine (reference:  decompiled code using ILSpy). But my understanding is the semantics hopefully same: both simply represent asynchronous work (task). But if one is failing, and other is not i would like to know the actual differences so that i can properly use TPL. It is possible it may be bug in TPL library, or my code. i am hoping it is later so that i can understand in details to fix my code.

Comment: @Dreamer, what exactly are you doing with the task returned by `IndefinitelyBlockingTask()`, can you show the relevant code?

Comment: @Dreamer, got it. See my updated answer (I had to undelete it as the original answer from 5 hours ago missed the mark completely).

Comment: @Noseratio, in the production code basically i have bunch of async methods which returns tasks (at the end of the day all these executes butch of http web requests using web client.uploaddatataskasync(...). essentially i have built two layers of async api on top of web client for my app (similar to the way web client relies on async functionality of httpwebrequest, stream, sockets underneath). Unfortuantely i don't have exact simple repro with my systems which dynamically aggregates bunch of tasks and wait on them finally. Debugger+threads/task windows are not showing useful info as well.

Comment: I suspect this question is now so confusing that it would be best if it was put on hold. It has been edited into a half-state where it is now not an original question, nor a question with an answer added onto the end, but a question with a partial answer fused into the middle, possibly with code modifications made to the code. I am not sure whether readers can learn from the Q&A while it is in this state.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, let's try to get to the bottom of what's happening here.

First things first: the difference in the lambda passed to your `ContinueWith` is insignificant: functionally that part is identical in the two examples (at least as far as I can see).

Here's the `FooAsync` implementation which I used for testing:

```
static Task FooAsync()
{
    return Task.Delay(500);
}
```

What I found curious is that using this implementation your `IndefinitelyBlockingTask` took twice as long as `TaskWhichWorks` (1 second vs ~500 ms respectively). Obviously the behaviour has changed due to `Unwrap`.

Someone with a keen eye would probably spot the problem right away, but personally I don't use task continuations *or* `Unwrap` that much, so it took a little while to sink in.

Here's the kicker: unless you use `Unwrap` on the continuation in both cases the task scheduled by `ContinueWith` completes synchronously (and immediately - regardless of how long the tasks created inside the loop take). The task created inside the lambda (`Task.WhenAll(childTasks.ToArray())`, let's call it inner task) is scheduled in a fire-and-forget fashion and runs onobserved.

`Unwrap`ping the task returned from `ContinueWith` means that the inner task is no longer fire-and-forget - it is now part of the execution chain, and when you add it to the list, the outer task (`Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray())`) cannot complete until the inner task has completed).

Using `ContinueWith(async () => { })` does not change the behaviour described above, because the task returned by the async lambda is not auto-unwrapped (think

```
// These two have similar behaviour and
// are interchangeable for our purposes.
Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(500))
Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(500));
```

vs

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Task.Delay(500))
```

The `Task.Run` call has `Unwrap` built-in (see http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#0fb2b4d9262599b9#references); the `StartNew` call doesn't and the task that it returns just completes immediately without waiting for the inner task. `ContinueWith` is similar to `StartNew` in that regard.

**Side note**

Another way to reproduce the behaviour observed when you use `Unwrap` is to make sure that tasks created inside the loop (or their continuations) are attached to the parent causing the parent task (created by `ContinueWith`) not to transition to the completed state until all child tasks have finished.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    var ct = FooAsync().ContinueWith(_ => { }, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
    childTasks.Add(ct);
}
```

**Back to original problem**

In your current implementation even if you had `await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray())` as the last line of the outer method, the method would still return *before* the tasks created inside the `ContinueWith` lambda have completed. Even if the tasks created inside `ContinueWith` never complete (my guess is that's exactly what's happening in your production code), *the outer method will still return just fine*.

So there it is, all things unexpected with the above code are caused by the silly `ContinueWith` which essentially "falls through" unless you use `Unwrap`. `async`/`await` is in no way the cause or the cure (although, admittedly, it can and probably should be used to rewrite your method in a more sensible way - continuations *are* difficult to work with leading to problems such as this one).

**So what's happening in production**

All of the above leads me to believe that there is a deadlock inside one of the tasks spun up inside your `ContinueWith` lambda causing that innner `Task.WhenAll` to never complete in production trim.

Unfortunately you have not posted a concise repro of the problem (I suppose I could do it for you armed with the above information, but it's really not my job to do so) or even the production code, so this is as much of a solution as I can give.

The fact that you weren't observing the described behaviour with your pseudo code should have hinted that you probably ended up stripping out the bit which was causing the problem. If you think that sounds silly, it's because it is, which is why I ended up retracting my original upvote for the question despite the fact that it is was the single most curious async problem I came across in a while.

**CONCLUSION: Look at your `ContinueWith` lambda.**

**Final edit**

You insist that `Unwrap` and `await` do similar things, which is true (not really as it ultimately messes with task composition, but kind of true - at least for the purpose of this example). However, having said that, you never fully recreated the `Unwrap` semantics using `await`, so is there really a big surprise that the method behaves differently? Here's `TaskWhichWorks` with an `await` that will behave similarly to the `Unwrap` example (it is also vulnerable to the deadlocking issues when applied to your production code):

```
static async Task TaskWhichUsedToWorkButNotAnymore()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    Task task = FooAsync();
    tasks.Add(task);
    Task<Task> continuationTask = task.ContinueWith(async t =>
    {
        List<Task> childTasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            var ct = FooAsync();
            childTasks.Add(ct);
        }
        Task wa = Task.WhenAll(childTasks.ToArray());
        await wa.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    tasks.Add(continuationTask);

    // Let's Unwrap the async/await way.
    // Pay attention to the return type.
    // The resulting task represents the
    // completion of the task started inside
    // (and returned by) the ContinueWith delegate.
    // Without this you have no reference, and no
    // way of waiting for, the inner task.
    Task unwrappedTask = await continuationTask;

    // Boom! This method now has the
    // same behaviour as the other one.
    tasks.Add(unwrappedTask);

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

    // Another way of "unwrapping" the
    // continuation just to drive the point home.
    // This will complete immediately as the
    // continuation task as well as the task
    // started inside, and returned by the continuation
    // task, have both completed at this point.
    await await continuationTask;
}
```

Comment: @Kiril, ">>>the inner task is no longer fire-and-forget<<<" - yes, that is exactly my intention. I don't want to leave any task result observed. ">>>the outer method will still return just fine.<<<" yes, thats true too - either with async/await in lambda, or using Unwrap am keeping track of "inner task (Task.whenall(childtasks)) - note continue with returns Task<Task>. ">>>Look at your ContinueWith lambda." - yes, am started looking at it in details. But the thing which puzzled me is if there is deadlock, it should lock with both cases as both asyn/await and unwrap tracks inner task.

Comment: @Kiril, just to accentuate the fact, yes pretty sure there is something am missing in production which am planning to focus on, if possible provide a repro. But, the things which puzzled me as it should deadlock in both cases. And 'Debugger+Threads' don't show any other threads, only my one threads which is simply waiting on event (please see the callstack i attached in the question). I will try to see if it repros in win7 and see if i can track tasks (for some reason debugger + tasks doesn't show any details). Its kind of difficult to debug or get exact repro because of all these nested taks.

Comment: @Dreamer, you could just as easily plonk `tasks.Add(continuationTask.Unwrap())` into your second example thus causing the deadlock. `async`/`await` usage really doesn't come into play here, at all.

Comment: @Dreamer, the stack is clear as day: I crawled through the call path on ReferenceSource to find that pesky `MRES` (ultimately led to by a call to `Task.Wait()` somewhere). It's a classic deadlock (or possibly an async deadlock), and I have just told you exactly where to look for it. All of the code posted in the question (I mean it: *all* of it) is just fluff around the real issue and doesn't contribute to the deadlock.

Comment: @First of all i really appreciate your time and answer:). yes, task.wait(..) in the callstack clearly shows one of the tasks is not signaling as completed. but, when using async/await it lambda something is signaling it. whereas, with unwrap(..) nothing is signaling (note both simply uses same continue with block to create child tasks in same fashion and returns inner task to track overall result). I will take a closer look and try to provide you guys with some more details, if i discover/identify anything interested.

Comment: @Kiril, note i can simply ignore unwrap, and use async/await pattern in lamadas as well as i know it works. but, i want to know exact reason, as i am pretty if i ignore them, it re-appear at customer's environment. thats what experience taught me - attack the problem, before it becomes serious :). Hopefully i find the answer...

Comment: @Dreamer, skipping `Unwrap` changes the task execution (and completion) sequence. With `Unwrap`, tasks inside the loop need to complete in order for the outer method to complete - if they can't complete, the method can't complete. Without it there's nothing waiting for the inner tasks, so they're started, the outer method completes, possibly some external code runs (and I'm guessing releases the locked resource in the process or once finished) and THEN the inner tasks get to complete at some point in the future, hence you avoid the deadlock.

Comment: @Kiril, exactly ">>>With Unwrap, tasks inside the loop need to complete in order for the outer method to complete <<<": but note that unwrap returns immediately with proxy asyn task. that is exactly the contract of async/await as well. After await, compiler generates code which simply returns proxy asynchronous task and returns immediately. Similarly unwrap (my understanding) returns proxy task asynchronously(lets call them innertasks as per ur answer). So final wait, waits on inner task to complete - i.e. essentially same semantics (async/await, succeeds but not unwrap). that's the puzzle :(

Comment: @Dreamer, there's really not much of a puzzle. I caught on to it, Carsten König caugt on to it, and so will you. You appear to have the right ideas, but you're mixing them up. Let me present one more pointer: `await Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith(_ => Task.Delay(500)).Unwrap()` is actually roughly equivalent to `await await Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith(_ => Task.Delay(500))` and also roughly equivalent to `await await Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith(async _ => await Task.Delay(500))`. Unless I see that funny-looking extra `await` in your code, you're *not* recreating what `Unwrap` does.

Comment: @Kril, +1 - Awesome, thank you. that's the difference :). I am not doing what unwrap does. After adding 'extra' await on 'conituation task' its blocking in production too. If I figure it out actual deadlock, will go ahead and accept this as answer as you helped me to figure it out. Else, will provide concise repro as suggested to continue the discussion. And yes, at this stage this is the best answer with the information I have provided to you.

Answer (score 2):

I have accepted Kirill's answer as the actual answer as it helped me to resolve the problem. Here I am adding few details which probably directly address both questions in concise manner as now I have concise repro for deadlock as well (please see edited version of the question):

a. deadlock is happening because contianuation task is waiting on all outer tasks which contains proxy of the 'continuation task:)'

b. I have pasted the await version of deadlock for reference.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task withUnwrap = Unwrap_IndefinitelyBlockingTask();
            Task<Task> withAwait = AwaitVersion_IndefinitelyBlockingTask();
            withAwait.Wait();
            //withUnwrap.Wait();
        }
        static async Task<Task> AwaitVersion_IndefinitelyBlockingTask()
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            Task task = FooAsync();
            tasks.Add(task);
            Task<Task<Task>> continuationTask = task.ContinueWith(async t =>
            {
                //immediately returns with generated Task<Task> return type task 
                await Task.Delay(10000);
                List<Task> childtasks = new List<Task>();
                ////get child tasks
                //now INSTEAD OF ADDING CHILD TASKS, i added outer method TASKS. Typo :(:)!
                //!!since we added compiler generated task to outer task its deadlock!!
                Task wa = Task.WhenAll(tasks/*TYPO*/);
                await wa.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
                return wa;
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
            tasks.Add(continuationTask);
            //Task unwrappedTask = continuationTask.Unwrap();
            Task<Task> awaitedComiplerGeneratedTaskOfContinuationTask = await continuationTask;
            tasks.Add(awaitedComiplerGeneratedTaskOfContinuationTask);
            Task whenall = Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
            return whenall;
        }
        static async Task FooAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(20000);
        }
```

Comment: Well done chasing it down. And yeah, that typo is a showstopper. I had a feeling it would be something along these lines which is why I said that it's either a classic deadlock (which is harder to run into when you have no `SynchronizationContext`) or an `async` "deadlock". Either way, glad you got it right in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your scheduler can schedule intermediate continuation on the blocked thread.

---

> ### Original Source:   http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html
>
> > ### Deadlock
> >
> > Here’s the situation: remember from my intro post that after you await
> >     a Task, when the method continues it will continue in a context.
> >
> > In the first case, this context is a UI context (which applies to any
> >     UI except Console applications). In the second case, this context is
> >     an ASP.NET request context.
> >
> > One other important point: an ASP.NET request context is not tied to a
> >     specific thread (like the UI context is), but it does only allow one
> >     thread in at a time. This interesting aspect is not officially
> >     documented anywhere AFAIK, but it is mentioned in my MSDN article
> >     about SynchronizationContext.
> >
> > So this is what happens, starting with the top-level method
> >     (Button1_Click for UI / MyController.Get for ASP.NET):
>
> The top-level method calls GetJsonAsync (within the UI/ASP.NET
>   context). GetJsonAsync starts the REST request by calling
>   HttpClient.GetStringAsync (still within the context). GetStringAsync
>   returns an uncompleted Task, indicating the REST request is not
>   complete. GetJsonAsync awaits the Task returned by GetStringAsync. The
>   context is captured and will be used to continue running the
>   GetJsonAsync method later. GetJsonAsync returns an uncompleted Task,
>   indicating that the GetJsonAsync method is not complete. The top-level
>   method synchronously blocks on the Task returned by GetJsonAsync. This
>   blocks the context thread. … Eventually, the REST request will
>   complete. This completes the Task that was returned by GetStringAsync.
>   The continuation for GetJsonAsync is now ready to run, and it waits
>   for the context to be available so it can execute in the context.
>   Deadlock. The top-level method is blocking the context thread, waiting
>   for GetJsonAsync to complete, and GetJsonAsync is waiting for the
>   context to be free so it can complete. For the UI example, the
>   “context” is the UI context; for the ASP.NET example, the “context” is
>   the ASP.NET request context. This type of deadlock can be caused for
>   either “context”.
>
> ### Preventing the Deadlock
>
> There are two best practices (both covered in
>   my intro post) that avoid this situation:
>
> In your “library” async methods, use ConfigureAwait(false) wherever
>   possible. Don’t block on Tasks; use async all the way down.